# ListView appearing with RadioButton

Tags: android, android-listview

the listView always appears with a radiobutton so is there any way to remove this radiobutton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize each item's layout using a proper Adapter. What you are seeing is the layout given by android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, which is the default, but you can override that with something like:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.my_array, R.layout.my_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can find more information in the Spinner Tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html